# Get values from textfield and store them in dictionary in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, for-loop, uitextfield, nsdictionary

I have a `textfield` in a `tableviewcell`. On button click i want to store values from textfield in a dictionary.
But one of the textfield is returning nil though having value in it.

```
NSString *sEmpty= [[NSString alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){

  myProfileCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

  sEmpty = cell.tfProfileDetails.text;

  if (sEmpty == nil) {
   sEmpty = @"";
  }

  NSString *str;

  switch (i) {
   case 0:
    str = @"first_name";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 1:
    str = @"middle_name";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 2:
    str = @"last_name";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 3:
    str = @"profile";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 4:
    str = @"email";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 5:
    str = @"phone";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 6:
    str = @"birth_date";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 7:
    str = @"sex";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 8:
    str = @"city";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 9:
    str = @"bio";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 10:
    str = @"address";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 11:
    str = @"pincode";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   case 12:
    str = @"bank_acc_type";
    [_userDict setObject:sEmpty forKey:str];
    sEmpty = nil;

    break;

   default:
    break;
  }


}


NSLog(@ "%@ ",_userDict);
```

When the code comes to **case 11 (pincode)** - the textfield stores nil value in **sEmpty** but i entered the values in all the textfield on the simulator.
Please suggest me some possible outcome so that all the values gets stored in the dictionary.

P.S - If the value in the textfield is empty then the value in the dictionary is stored as an empty string

Comment: Your entire approach is incorrect. Don't use the cells to store the text. Don't iterate the index paths to get all of the cells to get each piece of text. That will never work. You need to update your data model as soon as any given text field resigns being first responder.

Comment: ohk can you show me the correct approach through codes? @rmaddy

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. I am not even sure that your view implementation works if the cells are more than a given number, because when a cell disappears (i.e. when the user scrolls the tableview) and then reappears, I am fairly sure that its content will be empty

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's document for [cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath?language=objc). This method will return

> An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

As I guess, the table view displays 11 cells and `pincode` is 12th cell which isn't visible on screen. That makes `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return `nil` for cell at this index path, leading to text field and `sEmpty` is `nil`.

To resolve it, I suggest to keep strings in an array. Whenever user types on a text field, update the string value at this index. When you need to strings, get from array instead of cells

Comment: how can i overcome this situation ??

Comment: I don't have enough information about your code to do it. As I see, you keep `_userDict` as a model. What you should do now is updating `_userDict` whenever a text field changes.

Comment: i want to know which methods should i call while changing the textfield

Comment: you should implement some logic in the cell's class. For instance you might (as an example) post a notification when the `textfieldDidEndEditing` is being fired, and listen to that notification in the containing view controller. Or set the view controller as the cell's delegate, and call a delegate method from the cell (again, when the user ends editing the textfield).